# Why Azure SQL Server table used space is too high?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have two tables in my SQLServer database (azure managed), and the structure of two tables as below (for easy reference renamed them)

**dbo.TABLE1**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE1] (
  [ID]             VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,  -- PK index
  [S_NUMBER]       VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
  [MAKE]           VARCHAR (12)  NULL,
  [MODEL]          VARCHAR (40)  NULL,
  [C_ID]          VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
  [C_CODE]         REAL          NULL,
  [C_DESCRIPTION]  VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
  [S_CODE]         REAL          NULL,
  [S_DESCRIPTION]  VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
  [LS_TIME]       DATETIME2 (7) NOT NULL,
  [LE_TIME]        DATETIME2 (7) NOT NULL,
  [YEAR]           DATE          NULL,
  [MONTH]          DATE          NULL,
  [WEEK]           DATE          NULL,
  [DAY]            DATE          NULL,
  [HOUR]           DATETIME2 (7) NULL,
  [WEEK_DAY]       VARCHAR (12)  NULL,
  [F_USED]         REAL          NULL,
  [F_USED_UOM]     VARCHAR (12)  NULL,
  [DIST_TRAVE]     REAL          NULL,
  [DIST_TRAV_UOM]  VARCHAR (12)  NULL,
  [DURATION]      REAL          NULL,
  [DURATION_UOM]   VARCHAR (12)  NULL,
  [WEIGHT_MOVED]   REAL          NULL,
  [WEIGHT_STORED]  REAL          NULL,
  [WEIGHT_UOM]     VARCHAR (12)  NULL,
  [CREATED_TIME]   DATETIME      NULL,
  [MODIFIED_TIME]  DATETIME      NULL,
  [OPER_ID]        VARCHAR (12)  NULL,
  [OPER_TYPE]      VARCHAR (12)  NULL,
  [START_TIME]     DATETIME2 (7) NULL,
  [END_TIME]       DATETIME2 (7) NULL,
  [UTC_DAY]        DATE          NULL,
  [UTC_WEEK]       DATE          NULL,
  [UTC_MONTH]      DATE          NULL,
  [UTC_YEAR]       SMALLINT      NULL,
  [UTC_HOUR]       TINYINT       NULL,
  [LOCAL_HOUR]     TINYINT       NULL,
  [EFFICIENCY]     DECIMAL (5)   NULL,
  [JS_ID]          BIGINT        NOT NULL,
  [L_ZONE]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
  [D_ZONE]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
  [SHIFT_TYPE]     NVARCHAR (12) NULL,
  [SHIFT_DATE]     DATE          NULL,
  [D_CATEGORY]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
  [REC_CATEGORY]   NVARCHAR (12) NULL,
  [LSERIAL_NUMBER] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
  [GPS_TIME]       DATETIME      NULL,
  [GPS_STATUS]     VARCHAR (12)  NULL,
  [A_ID]           VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
  [E_ID]           VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
  [TAG_GUID]       VARCHAR (64)  NULL,
  [LZ_ID]          VARCHAR (64)  NULL,
  [DZ_ID]          VARCHAR (64)  NULL,
  [LZ_VERSION]     INT           NULL,
  [DZ_VERSION]     INT           NULL,
  [Z_ID]           BIGINT        NULL,
  [SHIFT_ID]       NVARCHAR (64) NULL,
  [LI_TIME]        DATETIME2 (3) CONSTRAINT [S_CREATED_TIMESTAMP] DEFAULT (sysdatetime()) NULL,
  [PC_ID] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  [L_MAKE]               VARCHAR (32)    NULL, 
  [TV_MOVED]        DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL
);
```

**dbo.TABLE2**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE2]( 
  [ID] NVARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,  -- PK index
  [C_ID] NVARCHAR(64),
  [DURATION] DECIMAL(18,2),
  [P_COUNT] BIGINT,
  [LS_TIME] DATETIME,
  [LE_TIME] DATETIME,
  [S_AGG_ID] NVARCHAR(32)   -- FK index
)
```

**dbo.TABLE2** is subset of **dbo.TABLE1** with only 5 columns, and the row count is same. We capture only 5 columns from **dbo.TABLE1** and insert in **dbo.TABLE2**. But the size(space used) of **dbo.TABLE2** is almost **3 times** the **dbo.TABLE1**.

**Indexes:** Apart from **PK**, **FK** indexes we have one additional index on **dbo.TABLE1** with include columns [JS_ID, MAKE, S_NUMBER, TAG_GUID, LE_TIME]

Why the space used is too high for smaller table even though row count is same as its source table?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218107/discussion-on-question-by-lovababu-why-azure-sql-server-table-used-space-is-too).

Answer (score 0):

### Using bigger data types

These columns in `dbo.Table1` are `varchar(50)`:

- `[ID]`
- `[C_ID]`

In `dbo.Table2`, they are `nvarchar(32)` and `nvarchar(64)`.

The added "n" makes each character take up twice as much space as the `varchar` version.  It's possible the same thing is going on with the FK column and `P_COUNT`, but I don't see those defined on the original table, so I can't confirm.

There are a couple of `datetime2(7)` columns changed to `datetime`, but these have the same storage cost, so that shouldn't make a difference.

If you get your data types back to what they were in the original table, you should see a pretty big reduction in space used.  Note that you will need to `REBUILD` the clustered index (or just drop and reload the table) after making the data types changes.

### Fragmentation?

It's possible that fragmentation is contributing to the additional size of `dbo.Table2`.  If the size is still significantly different after fixing the data types and recreating the table, you could try loading the table with `ORDER BY [ID] OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` to limit fragmentation in the target table.

Comment: That picture shows 22KB/row, which can't be explained by the data types or by fragmentation.  The rows are well under 500B, and bad fragmentation still leaves pages over 50% full.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Good point.  There is a lot of confusing information in the post though (OP says there are the same # of rows, but screenshot differs from that //  OP says table2 is a subset of the columns of table1, but some of the columns in table2 aren't present in table1 // etc) so I was just trying to highlight some things that *could* increase the size 